# codeigniter specifying limit to NULL not working in latest CI version 2.1.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, limit, codeigniter-2

I have following **get_authors_list** function in one of my Codeigniter model

```
function get_authors_list($limit,$offset){
    $data = array();

    $this->db->select('*')->from('authors')->limit($limit,$offset)->order_by('id','desc');

    $query = $this->db->get();         
    if ($query-> num_rows() >  0){
      $data = $query->result_array();
    }
    return $data;
    $q->free_result();
  }
```

Before upgrading to Codeigniter 2.1.2, I used call this method from my controller as

```
$data['authors'] = $this->author_model->get_authors_list(NULL, 0)
```

and it worked as expected but after upgrading to codeigniter version 2.1.2 it doesn't work, to get it working I had to specify limit as follows in my function call

```
$data['authors'] = $this->author_model->get_authors_list(50, 0)
```

That's specifying limit to NULL is not working, why? Am I doing anything wrong here? 
I followed Codeigniter's upgrade instruction correctly but it's some side effect I didn't expect.

Any explanation is welcome.
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, it won't work because, in the [latest version of CodeIgniter](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/tree/2.1-stable) in their [`System/Database/DB_active_rec.php`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php) file, **they made a change** to a line in `limit` function of *earlier* versions:

```
$this->ar_limit = $value;
```

is now,

```
$this->ar_limit = (int) $value;
```

So, `(int) null` is being converted to `0`, and, **you are not getting any results**.

So I think you have to remove the `limit` call totally. Why do you need to set it to `null` anyway?

Comment: He probably wants it to return every rows that the DBMS can find.

Comment: Ok, one noob question: doesn't 'not setting limit' return everything?

Comment: Yes. The OP should've just checked to see if `$limit` is equal to `NULL`. If it is not, call the `limit()` method, otherwise just continue the operation. But I guess he wants to keep the code as minimal as possible or something like that.

Comment: @goldenparrot I want to use this function for paginated pages and other locations. So sometimes I want to get all the results and sometimes not and keep the code as minimal as possible

Comment: @KemalFadillah For now I have just specified limit where needed and it's working fine.I am thinking of checking for $limit if it's null and customize code accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work anymore. There's been a change in the source code that will now ignore `NULL` value. See this [commit](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/b0eae5f81a4cb92911bb215ad814ae5caef4f61d).

Comment: I think there might be a clarification here: the OP is using 2.1-stable branch, and you were referring to a patch of different branch? so basically after that patch, it SHOULD work, right?

Comment: @goldenparrot my bad. I've fixed the link to the right commit.