# Issue in creating datatable with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

I am trying to create Datatable with CodeIgniter using [these files](https://github.com/blake-nouribekian/codeigniter-datatables).

In data.php(controller) which I've renamed to datatable.php I added "$this->getTable();" in function index() and only defined $aColumns and $sTable according to my need. No other changes are made.

I run the code using this URL : "localhost/codeigniter/index.php/datatable"
I am new to this so still not removed the index.php and I don't use base_url so I accordingly made changes in index.php while loading scripts and css. Also I've changed the sAjaxSource to datatable/getTable and class name to Datatable as I've changed the file name.

The main problem is the execution is not entering this foreach loop. The echo statement is not executed.

```
foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow)
    {
        echo '123';
        $row = array();

        foreach($aColumns as $col)
        {
            $row[] = $aRow[$col];
        }

        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
```

And I get the output as follows:

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":32,"iTotalDisplayRecords":"32","aaData":[]}
```

The aaData should display the 32 records in JSON format but it is not doing so. I am not getting where am I wrong ?

Appended:
getTable() function:

```
public function getTable()
{
    $aColumns = array('student_id', 'exam_id', 'subject_id', 'marks_achieved');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "student_id";

    // DB table to use
    $sTable = 'marks';
    //

    $iDisplayStart = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayStart', true);
    $iDisplayLength = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayLength', true);
    $iSortCol_0 = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_0', true);
    $iSortingCols = $this->input->get_post('iSortingCols', true);
    $sSearch = $this->input->get_post('sSearch', true);
    $sEcho = $this->input->get_post('sEcho', true);

    // Paging
    if(isset($iDisplayStart) && $iDisplayLength != '-1')
    {
        $this->db->limit($this->db->escape_str($iDisplayLength), $this->db->escape_str($iDisplayStart));
    }

    // Ordering
    if(isset($iSortCol_0))
    {
        for($i=0; $i<intval($iSortingCols); $i++)
        {
            $iSortCol = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_'.$i, true);
            $bSortable = $this->input->get_post('bSortable_'.intval($iSortCol), true);
            $sSortDir = $this->input->get_post('sSortDir_'.$i, true);

            if($bSortable == 'true')
            {
                $this->db->order_by($aColumns[intval($this->db->escape_str($iSortCol))], $this->db->escape_str($sSortDir));
            }
        }
    }


    if(isset($sSearch) && !empty($sSearch))
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($aColumns); $i++)
        {
            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_'.$i, true);

            // Individual column filtering
            if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
            {
                $this->db->or_like($aColumns[$i], $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
            }
        }
    }

    // Select Data
    $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS '.str_replace(' , ', ' ', implode(', ', $aColumns)), false);
    $rResult = $this->db->get($sTable);

    // Data set length after filtering
    $this->db->select('FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows');
    $iFilteredTotal = $this->db->get()->row()->found_rows;

    // Total data set length
    $iTotal = $this->db->count_all($sTable);

    // Output
    $output = array(
        'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
        'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
        'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
        'aaData' => array()
    );
    foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow)
    {
        echo '123';
        $row = array();

        foreach($aColumns as $col)
        {
            $row[] = $aRow[$col];
        }

        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Regarding SQL code, I've added the records manually in phpmyadmin not using queries.

Any issues in the SQL code ?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `marks` (
`student_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`exam_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`subject_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`marks_achieved` int(10) NOT NULL,
KEY `student_id` (`student_id`),
KEY `exam_id` (`exam_id`),
KEY `subject_id` (`subject_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I tested the code, and it works fine as is. What is the structure of your database? Did you notice that according to the function the columns are 'id', 'first_name' and 'last_name'?

Comment: I have kept my columns as follows :
$aColumns = array('student_id', 'exam_id', 'subject_id', 'marks_achieved');
And table as follows :
$sTable = 'marks';

Comment: I modified the table with the columns you specified, and I modified the controller as well. After running, the JSON output was perfect. Please edit your question to post your SQL code and the entire  getTable() funciton.

Comment: With phpMyAdmin, you can click on 'export' to download the SQL file. Your controller looks almost exactly like mine. Try troubleshooting your variables. You can use print_r() in the getTable() function to show your query results. You can echo your last query with $this->db->last_query();

Comment: I swapped your getTable() function for mine. You're echoing '123' in your loop, but besides that, your code works great. You must have some problem with your database.

Comment: Right after the comment "Data set length after filtering," enter "echo  $this->db->last_query();" The database query should appear on your screen. Click n the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin and paste the query in the textbox and run it. What happens?

Comment: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS student_id, exam_id, subject_id, marks_achieved FROM (`marks`) LIMIT 0

The LIMIT 0 is the problem, if I change it to 10 or so records are displayed. I have the same code as I've posted where is the mistake ?

Comment: See the edited comments about changing line number 35. Run that and see what happens. I don't have much time right now to try it out, so I hope that does the trick. If not, I'll have to work on it tomorrow.

Comment: If you are using codeigniter, use Ignited datatable library. It will save lot of time. And it is easy too.

Comment: Yea I saw that too. But I found this one analogous to the native PHP code of datatables.net server side processing example so used it.By the way I've ended up displaying the datatables w/o server side processing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `marks` (
  `student_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `exam_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `marks_achieved` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `marks` (`student_id`, `exam_id`, `subject_id`, `marks_achieved`) VALUES
(1, 210, 340, 'really good'),
(2, 220, 440, 'super');
```

Edit the getTables() function to specify the columns:

```
$aColumns = array('student_id', 'exam_id', 'subject_id', 'marks_achieved');
```

Change the name off the table, editing this line:

```
$sTable = 'marks';
```

Your table probably isn't exactly like this, but I had no problem getting this to work. Here's the JSON output that was echoed:

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":"2","aaData":[["1","210","340","really good"],["2","220","440","super"]]}
```

Change the following:

```
if(isset($iDisplayStart) && $iDisplayLength != '-1')
```

to:

```
if(( ! empty($iDisplayStart)) && $iDisplayLength != '-1')
```

It should be on or around line 35.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Problem solved. How was your code working the isset() function and mine isn't working ?

Comment: You must be running the latest version of Codeigniter. According to this link, they changed how the limit function works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365432/codeigniter-specifying-limit-to-null-not-working-in-latest-ci-version-2-1-2

Comment: Yes the limit is still causing issues. When I made the edit you said there is a problem. On the first draw all records are displayed instead of 10 which I have defined.